# Finding the value of a list view item and comparing it to a value in Azure Database

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, azure, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows store app for Windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 using C# and XAML.

I have a table that stores goals and rewards, these are displayed in a list view in my app. I want the user to be able to select one of these goals and have it marked as complete.

There is a column in my database which is set to false at the beginning and when the list view item is selected I want to find that item in the database and change the column to true.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? 
Here is my code:

```
private async void Goals_List_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a list of all names stored in goalsDetails table in DB
        var goalsComplete = new List<goalsDetails>(await goalsTable
                           .Where(goalsDetails => goalsDetails.UsernameID == goalsDetails.UsernameID && goalsDetails.Goal == goalsDetails.Goal && goalsDetails.Reward == goalsDetails.Reward && goalsDetails.GoalComplete == false)
                           .ToListAsync());

        for (int i = 0; i < goalsComplete.Count; i++)
        {
          //Goals_List is the name of my listview in XAML                
          if (Goals_List.SelectedIndex == i)
            {
                var user = goalsComplete.FirstOrDefault();

                // setting new details to push to database
                var newGoalDetails = new goalsDetails
                {
                    UsernameID = user.UsernameID,
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Goal = Goal_Text.Text,
                    GoalComplete = true,
                    DeadlineDate = Deadline_Date_Picker.Date.ToString("dd:MMMM:yyyy"),
                    ReminderTime = Reminder_Time_Picker.Time.ToString(),
                    Reward = Reward_Text.Text,
                };

                await goalsTable.UpdateAsync(newGoalDetails);
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when the item is selected in the listview, the value is never being changed to true.

Thanks! Any help would be MUCH appreciated!